# Using undo manager with mac catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uikit, mac-catalyst

I'm working on adding a mac build target to an iOS application. I have the basics working and would like to implement undo/redo functionality.

In a traditional AppKit application you get this for free. When you create a new application, the prepopulated main menu has the Edit item and Undo and Redo under it. The view controller has an `undoManager`, you just `registerUndo` on it (preferably `setActionName` as well) and everything works. Hotkeys, menu item title changes and state changes (disable redo when at the top of the stack etc.) all work out of the box.

Adding a catalyst build target to an iOS project also creates a default menu with a top level Edit menu and Undo/Redo menu items. These do not seem to adopt the built-in functionality. Do I really need to manually recreate all that is free with AppKit or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Registering undo on `NSWindow.undoManager` works for me. But I had to use a hidden/private API to access the `NSWindow` instance using [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) library:

```swift
let nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(view.window)
let undoManager: UndoManager? = nsWindow.undoManager
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working in my Catalyst app only by calling `becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidAppear` and no sooner. I was originally calling it in `viewDidLoad` and also tried `viewWillAppear`, neither of which correctly register my undo manager with macOS.

Relevant view controller sample code:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override var undoManager: UndoManager? {
        return myCustomUndoManager
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because it can't become a first responder unless it's part of the responder chain, which can't happen if it's not part of the view hierarchy. I would have tried this, but in my app, a drawing app, I have a separate undo manager for each layer so undo/redo can be done on a per layer basis. The counterpart to viewDidAppear that I tried was when I activate a layer (user taps layer it becomes the active layer. The rest I just copied. But it didn't work. The Redo/Undo remain unavailable. Next I'll try tying to the VC and have the VC trigger the layer's undo manager.

Comment: Actually, I think I'll just remove the undo/redo menu items and re-add my own.

Comment: I got it to work, but I had to do the above overrides in the VC. The undoManager override set the undoManager from the active layer. I thought it wasn't working, but it was. I had omitted a setNeedsDisplay in the undo closure. So it was undoing/redoing but not updating the display.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `becomeFirstResponder()` on the view that you're registering undo events? This was tripping me up for awhile.

I wasn't able to get action names to show up in the Catalyst Edit menu, but I did see the Undo/Redo stack working properly from UIKit code without having to dip into AppKit.